# xslt copy attribute from external document

Tags: xslt, saxon

I've following xml

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd">
    <changeSet author="system (generated)" id="1538720867962-1">
      <createTable tableName="AS_JOURNALEVENTDETAILATTRMAP">
            <column name="JOURNALEVENTTYPEID" type="NUMBER(9, 0)">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="PK$AS_JOURNALEVENTDETATTRMAP"/>
            </column>
            <column name="JOURNALEVENTDETAILATTRID" type="NUMBER(9, 0)">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="PK$AS_JOURNALEVENTDETATTRMAP"/>
            </column>
            <column name="LISTORDER" type="NUMBER(9, 0)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>
   </changeSet>
   <changeSet id="c529c6ea-45c2-4ec2-8c9d-7bc935434d21" author="system">
      <setTableRemarks remarks="this is wrong"
                       tableName="AS_JOURNALEVENTDETAILATTRMAP"/>
      <setColumnRemarks tableName="AS_JOURNALEVENTDETAILATTRMAP"
                        columnName="JOURNALEVENTTYPEID"
                        remarks="Journal event type identifier"/>
      <setColumnRemarks tableName="AS_JOURNALEVENTDETAILATTRMAP"
                        columnName="JOURNALEVENTDETAILATTRID"
                        remarks="Journal event detail attribute identifier"/>
      <setColumnRemarks tableName="AS_JOURNALEVENTDETAILATTRMAP"
                        columnName="LISTORDER"
                        remarks="Order in list"/>
   </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

and the exact same document with name `fixedremarks.xml` but there is little change `<setTableRemarks remarks="this is ok" tableName="AS_JOURNALEVENTDETAILATTRMAP"/>`

with following template I'm trying to fix attribute `remarks` inside `setTableRemarks` but without success - I don't know how to properly copy that attribute from external xml.

```
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
               xpath-default-namespace="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
               xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="originalChangeLog" select="document('/tmp/fixedremarks.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:key name="remarkTableName" match="setTableRemarks" use="@tableName"/>

    <xsl:template match="changeSet[setTableRemarks]">
        <xsl:variable name="currentRemarkTable" select="setTableRemarks/@tableName"/>
        <xsl:comment select="$currentRemarkTable"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:element name="setTableRemarks">

                <xsl:attribute name="remarks"
                               select="$originalChangeLog/key('remarkTableName', $currentRemarkTable)"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="tableName" select="setTableRemarks/@tableName"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::setTableRemarks)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

can somebody tell me how to map properly remark from external document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want the identity transformation template you have plus

```
<xsl:template match="changeSet/setTableRemarks[key('remarkTableName', @tableName, $originalChangeLog)]/@remarks">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="key('remarkTableName', ../@tableName, $originalChangeLog)/@remarks"/>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwR has an online sample (there the secondary XML is inlined as a variable for a self-contained example but if you keep your `<xsl:variable name="originalChangeLog" select="document('/tmp/fixedremarks.xml')"/>` it will work as well.